# Custom query Hibernate with conditional where clause and count

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I would like to have a custom query with several condition : 
 - Conditional where clause 
 - join between 2 tables
 - count and group by

So something like this :

```
SELECT items.*, count(1) FROM ITEMS items, USER user 
WHERE items.id = user.item_id
AND item.color = 'red'
AND item.size = 'big'
GROUP BY items.id;
```

And depending on the parameters (color and size), some WHERE clause will not be used.

Is it even possible?
I have an Entity for "items" and I created a new Entity that contains a List and a int (for the count(1) ).

I don't really know how to do this with Hibernate and I don't know where to start.

Comment: Can you share your entity class code ?

Comment: I didn't code because I don't really know how to do this. I can't do this with @Query from JPA because I can't change the query when I need to add/remove a WHERE condition..